# Implementing a Generic C# class using method in common to others

Tags: c#, class, generics

I have the following problem in `C#`.

I have two classes exposing some common members and methods, for example:

```
Class myClass01{
   public int a;
   public int b;
   public void method_01(){...}
   public void method_A(){...}
}
```

and

```
Class myClass02{
   public int a;
   public int b;
   public void method_01(){...}
   public void method_B(){...}
}
```

I want to create a new generic `class` that can use the common attributes/methods of both of them. For example:

```
Class myGeneric<T>{
   public T element;

   public int sum(){
       return element.a + element.b;
   }

   public void methodGeneric(){
       element.method_01();
    }
}
```

But with this kind of implementation I receive errors because elements are not accessible. Is there a way to a create a generic class using methods/attributes from different classes but equally defined?

Comment: Why not to use interface or abstract class ?

Comment: Please have a look at naming conventions when you have time http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic `class` you are making currently does not have a constraint to know from what `class` the generic type `T` must be derived from. Thus, it assumes `object` which does not recognized any customized `public/protected` fields, properties, and methods you implement.

If you want the generic `T` to recognize the `public/protected` fields, properties, and methods you have in common between two classes, you should create an `interface` which is implemented by both classes and you have the generic type `T` derived from that particular `interface`.

For example:

```
public interface ImyClass { //this is the common interface
    int a { get; set; }
    int b { get; set; }
    void method_01();
}

class myClass01 : ImyClass { //your special interface implementation for myClass01
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public void method_01() { }
    public void method_A() { }
}

class myClass02 : ImyClass {  //your special interface implementation for myClass02
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public void method_01() { }
    public void method_B() { }
}
```

Then in your generic, constraint the generic type with the `interface`

```
class myGeneric<T> where T : ImyClass {
    public T element;

    public int sum() {              
        return element.a + element.b;
    }

    public void methodGeneric() {
        element.method_01();
    }
}
```

You could also use `abstract` or simple base `class` if the implementation for both methods (both `method_01`) happen to be exactly the same, for example:

```
public abstract class myAbstractClass { //this is the common abstract class or base class
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public void method_01(){ } // all your common implementations
}

public class myClass01 : myAbstractClass {
    public void method_A() { } //your special implementation for myClass01
}

public class myClass02 : myAbstractClass {
    public void method_B() { } //your special implementation for myClass02
}

class myGeneric<T> where T : myAbstractClass { //generic specifically from myAbstractClass 
    public T element;

    public int sum() {              
        return element.a + element.b;
    }

    public void methodGeneric() {
        element.method_01();
    }
}
```

In any case, a *common inheritance* is required to recognize the `public/protected` fields, properties, and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use Interfaces and "where" to get the members accessible. E.g.:

```
public class SortedList<T> : GenericList<T> where T : System.IComparable<T>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Note that in addition to Ians answer when using an interface, the generic is not necessary anymore you could simple use

```
class myGeneric {
    public ImyClass element;

    public int sum() {              
        return element.a + element.b;
    }

    public void methodGeneric() {
        element.method_01();
    }
}
```

Although it was not the actual question